# How to get JSON array as output instead of JSON object

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

in Azure Data Factory I have a pipeline which gets exchange rates from the ECB website as xml and apply transformations to it to get a json. It is working, however, right now, the output is a JSON object like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x73w2.png)

And I would like to have a JSON array as output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1yZY.png)

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your output JSON is an invalid JSON. The dataflow won't give the result JSON like yours. It will give the JSON file in a single JSON object file like below. Recheck your dataflow transformations.

```
{
"baseCurrency":"EUR",
"provider":"ECB",
"date":"2023-12-08",
"exchangeRates":[
{"currency":"USD","rate":1.0777},
{"currency":"JPY","rate":155.53},
{"currency":"BGN","rate":1.9558},
{"currency":"CZK","rate":24.354},
{"currency":"DKK","rate":7.4558},
{"currency":"GBP","rate":0.8569},
{"currency":"HUF","rate":381.9},
{"currency":"PLN","rate":4.3318},
{"currency":"RON","rate":4.9683},
{"currency":"SEK","rate":11.238},
{"currency":"CHF","rate":0.9438},
{"currency":"ISK","rate":150.1},
{"currency":"NOK","rate":11.727},
{"currency":"TRY","rate":31.234},
{"currency":"AUD","rate":1.6327},
{"currency":"BRL","rate":5.2933},
{"currency":"CAD","rate":1.4627},
{"currency":"CNY","rate":7.7179},
{"currency":"HKD","rate":8.419},
{"currency":"IDR","rate":16719.01},
{"currency":"ILS","rate":3.9982},
{"currency":"INR","rate":89.8875},
{"currency":"KRW","rate":1412.83},
{"currency":"MXN","rate":18.7923},
{"currency":"MYR","rate":5.0269},
{"currency":"NZD","rate":1.7532},
{"currency":"PHP","rate":59.758},
{"currency":"SGD","rate":1.4426},
{"currency":"THB","rate":38.097},
{"currency":"ZAR","rate":20.3657}
]
}
```

To convert this into an Array of Objects, use copy activity after dataflow activity. **Give the output JSON dataset of dataflow activity as source and sink of the copy activity**.

[image]

Give the same dataset as sink and in copy activity sink, select `Array of Objects` in the File pattern.

[image]

Debug the pipeline and you will get the desired JSON like below.

[image]